# PATH environment variable, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: path, environment-variables

I've never had to mess with my PATH before, but it seems simple enough. I just can't get it to work. I've made my path:

```
C:\Program Files\android-sdk_r08-windows\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools; C:\program files (x86)\Git\bin; C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin
```

I put the android-sdk in a while ago. I believe that worked, because the issue I had at the time was resolved. I've just added the jre6/bin folder for the keytool program and the Git/bin for the openssl tool. However, cmd still gives me the old "'blahblah' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". If I actually navigate to the folders in cmd, the programs work fine. If I reorder the PATH variable, the first path on the list works, but the rest don't. Any idea what i've done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried removing the spaces after each semicolon?

Comment: Of course it is something as lttle as spaces. Thanks for the hint.